# Cleaning up csv data, w/ pandas is there a way to find first obj column that can be converted to #?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am reading a csv file to a pandas df. each row is a long url that i split by forward slashes.

In some cases, when i split the url there are more columns populated because the url has more forward slashes and the pattern is different. I am trying to find the first column that can convert to an integer and delete the columns before. the column won't be in integer form, it will be in object form as it was a string that can converted to an int (or to a float and then converted to an int).

Ultimately, I want to extract that numeric column and the last column (which is the end of the url) and everything in the middle can be deleted. In some cases there won't be a column that contains an is_numeric value, in which case I just want to extract the last column.

For example, after splitting the url I get a dataframe like the following: [in this example there are 4 columns, in mine there are 6, but it's the same thing i only want the first numeric and then the last column, and if there is not a first numeric column i just want the last column that ends in .html]

```
+--------------------------+-----------------+----------+------------------------+
|            1             |        2        |    3     |           4            |
+--------------------------+-----------------+----------+------------------------+
| 11100411                 | h_aa_kk_mm.html | None     | None                   |
| nnn                      | 51200411        | aa_bb_cc | k_yxxxxxxx_mmmm.html   |
| 11100411_h_aa_kk_mm.html | None            | None     | None                   |
| hmn                      | bb_a_34         | 76800616 | 999ccc-ddd.html        |
| nnn                      | 92503462        | v        | 66631xxxxffffkkka.html |
```

In this case, the result i would want is:

```
+----------+--------------------------+
|    1     |            2             |
+----------+--------------------------+
| 11100411 | h_aa_kk_mm.html          |
| 51200411 | k_yxxxxxxx_mmmm.html     |
| 76800616 | 999ccc-ddd.html          |
| 92503462 | 66631xxxxffffkkka.html   |
+----------+--------------------------+
```

df2  ..

```
 None     | 11100411_h_aa_kk_mm.html |
```

In the case where there is numeric column, those can be extracted into their own dataframe and i can deal with them separately.

I know i can do this by testing each case and column and using is_numeric, but the problem is if i do is_numeric i risk overwriting the end part of the html which i need and have to inefficiently check each scenario. the dataframe is currently 300,000 rows, so the easiest way where i dont confuse myself and lose track of the different cases is important as it's imperative i dont lose any of the data.

[I have read every stack overflow post i can find about this, but the case is slightly different and i tried various different ways for hours before posting]
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas tables are not be a good fit to deal with variable-length data. Consider not putting the url parts in a pandas table, and instead working with Python lists and normal Python functions.

```
parts = map(lambda s: s.split("/"), urls)
```

You can have a Python function to sort the url parts list into two piles. And then you can work on the first pile to find the first numeric value and the last valid value. Then put those into a DataFrame.

If you're set on using Pandas, you could write it something like this:

```
has_numeric = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.isnumeric().any(), axis=1)
df1 = df[has_numeric]
df2 = df[~has_numeric]
nums = df1.apply(lambda x: x[(x.str.isnumeric() == True).idxmax()], axis=1)
ends = df1.apply(lambda row: row[~row.isnull()].iloc[-1], axis=1)


>>> df
                          0                1         2                       3
0                  11100411  h_aa_kk_mm.html      None                    None
1                       nnn         51200411  aa_bb_cc    k_yxxxxxxx_mmmm.html
2  11100411_h_aa_kk_mm.html             None      None                    None
3                       hmn          bb_a_34  76800616         999ccc-ddd.html
4                       nnn         92503462         v  66631xxxxffffkkka.html

>>> df1
          0                1         2                       3
0  11100411  h_aa_kk_mm.html      None                    None
1       nnn         51200411  aa_bb_cc    k_yxxxxxxx_mmmm.html
3       hmn          bb_a_34  76800616         999ccc-ddd.html
4       nnn         92503462         v  66631xxxxffffkkka.html

>>> df2
                          0     1     2     3
2  11100411_h_aa_kk_mm.html  None  None  None

>>> nums 
0    11100411
1    51200411
3    76800616
4    92503462
dtype: object

>>> ends
0           h_aa_kk_mm.html
1      k_yxxxxxxx_mmmm.html
3           999ccc-ddd.html
4    66631xxxxffffkkka.html
dtype: object
```